# FFMPEG blending comes out looking grayscale rather than colourful

Tags: ffmpeg

When i do a blend of two pngs, it comes out looking grayscale whereas it should have colour.

These are the two PNG input assets that I then create MP4s from:-

[image]

[image]

Here is the command:-

```
ffmpeg -i black_circle.png -i pikachu.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1,format=rgb24[rgb1];[1:v]setsar=sar=1,format=rgb24[rgb2];[rgb1]split[out1_1][out1_2];[out1_1]crop=50:50:0:0:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped1];[cropped1][rgb2]blend=screen[blended1];[out1_2][blended1]overlay=0:0" pikachu_screened_on_circle_rgb.png
```

And here is the output:-

[image]

However, Pikachu should retain his Red, Green and Blue, but instead Pikachu looks grayscale.

I was wondering why this is ?

And what i need to do so that Pikachu retains his yellow skin, and rosey cheeks ?

So I thought initially that it might be something to do with the white and black circle being a grayscale asset.  But then I replaced the black and white circle with this asset:-

[image]

and I saw that when something is black FFMPEG makes it grayscale:-

[image]

The command using these two assets instead is this:-

```
ffmpeg -i rgb_backing.png -i pikachu.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1,format=rgb24[rgb1];[1:v]setsar=sar=1,format=rgb24[rgb2];[rgb1]split[out1_1][out1_2];[out1_1]crop=50:50:0:0:exact=1,setsar=1[cropped1];[cropped1][rgb2]blend=screen[blended1];[out1_2][blended1]overlay=0:0" pikachu_screened_on_rgb_backing.png
```

Is there a way to invert black to white in FFMPEG ?